# How to use a unique PNG for multiple tile?

Tags: leaflet

I want to use an offline map with Leaflet so I use PNG for my tiles.
I want to use a unique image for the water so I don't need to have a lot of identical PNG.

The files are stored this way 
myMap/z/x/y.png
With z the level of zoom, x and y the coordinate.

I think I can easily get the z, x and y of all the water tiles.
I just need to know if it's possible to tell Leaflet that if a tile with the same z, x and y than one in the array (or map or something else), it display myMap/water.png instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to do if you understand how [custom tilelayers in Leaflet work](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html). For this particular case you'll want a `getTileUrl` method that returns the same tile when some condition is met, e.g. something like:

```
L.TileLayer.RepeatedWater = L.TileLayer.extend({
    getTileUrl: function(coords) {

        if ( checkIfTheseCoordsAreInTheWater(coords) ) {
            return "/tiles/water.png";
        } else {
            return L.TileLayer.prototype.getTileUrl.call(this, coords);
        }
    }
});
```

Be aware that other approaches exists. In particular, a [service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) to intercept all network requests to the tiles, check if their URL is not out of bounds or not available (or whatever) and return a cached response from a "default water" tile in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have one question left. How can I combine this with native zoom? For exemple, I don't have zoom level 5, so I put a native zoom to 4 on a first layer and was switching, when going to zoom 6, to a second layer. Is it possible to reproduce this with custom tilelayers?